# How to add long press download pop up menu in Android browser?

Tags: java, android

How to add long press download pop up menu in Android browser, that will download images and other menus.
Also if possible provide me a code to download the image as I am making a browser which pop up menu will contain 
*Download image 
*Share image button

Comment: add code or best explain

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll try to include code next time.
Thanks for this answer and Link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourbutton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Also, you can also use [this link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-download-image-from-url/) to find how to download an image for an app